# Use of boost:mutex crashes plugin when on Windows 8

Tags: windows, boost-thread, firebreath

I am developing a cross-platform, cross browser NPAPI plugin based on Firebreath framework. I am using boost library 1.46.1 and boost::mutex in order to synchronize boost threads used in the program. The code compiles and runs as expected in Ubuntu and Windows 7 but when on Windows 8 browser freezes and plugin crashes. If I remove boost::mutex plugin works on Windows 8 as well. Is there any known issue with boost:mutex used in Windows 8? Any idea what could be causing this and how to debug it?

Comment: 1.46.1 was released in 2011... The current version of Boost is 1.55, released end 2013. Try recompiling with an up-to-date Boost.

Comment: Compiled and ran code using latest Firebreath release which uses boost library 1.50 but still when on Windows 8 browser freezes and plugin crashes. Any other ideas?

Comment: It will be helpful, if you provided a stack trace